# Is there any order for inheriting PermissionRequiredMixin in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I encountered this problem while following the [Django tutorial 8](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication).

I can redirect to the login page when I put `PermissionRequiredMixin` class first:

```py
class AuthorCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = '__all__'
    initial = {'date_of_death': '05/01/2018', }
    permission_required = 'catalog.add_author'
```

[image: result of First]

But when I put it in second position it doesn't work and goes directly to the page where the permission doesn't allow it:

```py
class AuthorCreate(CreateView, PermissionRequiredMixin):
```

[image: result of Second]

I want to know is whether I should always put the `PermissionRequiredMixin` class at the first position. And how about `LoginRequiredMixin`? or what if I inherit both？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and this is [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequiredmixin-mixin) for the `LoginRequiredMixin` mixin:

> This mixin should be at the leftmost position in the inheritance list.

It is not explicitly stated for `PermissionRequiredMixin` but it works the same way.

You should not need to inherit from both, as a user can't have the required permissions without logging in first, so `PermissionRequiredMixin` should be sufficient. If you really want to have both, `LoginRequiredMixin` should be the leftmost one.